# How do I solve this problem on matrices?

Tags: matrices

A club has m members with serial numbers $1,2,...,m$. If members with serial numbers $i$ and $j$ are friends, then $A(i,j)=A(j,i)=1$ otherwise $A(i,j)=A(j,i)=0$. By convention, $A(i,i)=0$, that is, a person cannot be friends with oneself. Let $A^k(i,j)$ refer to the $(i,j)th$ entry in the $kth$ power of the matrix $A$, that is $A^k$.

It is given that $A^9(i,j)>0$ for all pairs of $i,j$, where $i$ and $j$ are less than or equal to $m$, $A^2(1,2)>0$ and $A^4(1,3)=0$.

Then which of the following are true?
a) Member 1 and 2 have at least one friend in common.

I did this by taking $A$ as a square matrix of order 3, with diagonal entries equal to 0 as the problem mentions. After calculating $A^2$, with the given data in the problem, I found that members 3 and 2 are friends, and members 1 and 3 are friends. So 3 is the common friend in the least case scenario and this statement is true.

b) $A^2(i,i)>0$ for all i, i less than or equal to m.

The matrix $A^2$ turns out to have all non-zero entries so this is true.

c) m is less than or equal to 9.
d) m is greater than or equal to 6.

I cannot figure out how to do parts c) and d).

Comment: *"A person cannot be friend with oneself."* This is sad.

Comment: *"The matrix $A^2$ turns out to have all non-zero entries so this is true."*  How did you get this?  If true it implies $A^k$ is a positive matrix for $k\geq 2$.  That $A^2(i,i)\gt 0$ is weaker and implied by the fact that $A^9$ is a positive matrix

Comment: I just calculated $A^2$ for a square matrix $A$ of order 3 after putting the diagonal elements of $A$ equal to 0, and $A(1,3)=A(3,1)=1$ and $A(2,3)=A(3,2)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

(a) is true. Since $A^2(1,2)=\sum_{k=1}^mA(1,k)A(k,2)>0$, we have $A(1,k),A(k,2)>0$ for some $k$. However, by definition, $A(1,1)=A(2,2)=0$. Therefore $k\ne1,2$, meaning that member $k$ is a common friend to members $1$ and $2$.

(b) is true. Since $A^9>0$, $A$ is primitive and hence irreducible. It follows that for any given $i$, we must have $A(i,j)=1$ for some $j\ne i$. But then $A^2(i,i)\ge A(i,j)A(j,i)=1>0$.

(c) and (d) are false. For any $m\ge5$, consider the undirected graph where every node $k\ge5$ is only connected to node $4$ and the subgraph containing nodes $1$ to $5$ are connected in the following way: $3\leftrightarrow1\leftrightarrow4\leftrightarrow2\leftrightarrow5\leftrightarrow4$. Then $A^2(1,2)>0$ because the path $1\to4\to2$ has length $2$. Also, $A^4(1,3)=0$ because every path of length $\le4$ joining nodes $1$ and $3$ must have odd length. Finally, $A^9>0$: since every node (including node $4$) is connected to node $4$ by a path of length at most $2$, by appending an appropriate number of copies of the two-cycle $4\to1\to4$ and the three-cycle $4\to2\to5\to4$, every pair of nodes $i$ and $j$ are connected by a path of length $9$:
$$
i\to\cdots\to\underbrace{4\to\cdots\to4}_{\text{concatenation of two or three cycles}}\to\cdots\to j.
$$
In terms of matrix, for any $m\ge5$ (therefore $m$ can be smaller than $6$ or greater than $9$), if we put
$$
A=\pmatrix{B&e_4e^T\\ ee_4^T&0},
\ B=\pmatrix{
0&0&1&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&1\\
1&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&0&0&1\\
0&1&0&1&0}
$$
where $e=(1,1,1,1,1,\ldots,1)^T$ and $e_4=(0,0,0,1,0,\ldots,0)^T$, then $A^2(1,2)>0,\,A^4(1,3)=0$ and $A^9>0$.